# Separar un string utilizando como parámetro una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo que separar un string X a partir de una lista de argumentos, intenté pasar como argumento al método split() la lista en la cual están los separadores, pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: must be str or None, not list
```

Investigué e intenté utilizar la función re.split, pero tampoco me sirvió.

Muestra del código:

```
puntuation = [',', ';', ' ']
words_list = []
un_texto = "Hola, cómo estás?"
words_list = un_texto.split(puntuation)

print(words_list)
```

Por otra parte, me serviría mucho si me darían una recomendación de como buscar por mí parte solución a estos problemas, busqué por W3 Schools, busqué ayuda tanto en inglés como en español, pero no encontré nada.

Comment: Creo que lo que buscas es algo asi     words_list = re.split(', |; | ', un_texto)    no olvides import re

Comment: el error te lo dice, entoces words_list = un_texto.split(puntuation[0])donde le agrego el índice de uno de los elementos, mi pregunta es¿por cuál de todos quereés separar?,si es por orden,o sea el que se encuentre primero, recorre la lista y si el elemento se encuentra en la cadena, ahí separas,sino pasas al siguiente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

```
import re

puntuation = [',', ';', ' ']
un_texto = "Hola, cómo estás?"
words_list = re.split(r"[{}]".format(''.join(puntuation)), un_texto)

# words_list contendrá lo siguiente: ['Hola', '', 'cómo', 'estás?']
# Si deseas quitar la string nula, puedes hacer:

words_list = [word for word in words_list if word]
# Con lo cual ahora words_list contendrá: ['Hola', 'cómo', 'estás?']
```

### Explicación

Lo que estás buscando es (como sugirió Andrés en los comentarios) la función `split` del módulo `re`.

Esta función toma dos argumentos posicionales: `pattern` y `string`. El primero es una expresión regular y el segundo la string a la que se aplicará la separación (split). Para conseguir lo que deseas deberás pasar los siguientes valores a ellos:

- pattern: `r"[{}]".format(''.join(puntuation))`
- string: `un_texto`

Vamos a analizar qué se está pasando a `pattern`:

1. La `r` antepuesta a la string significa "raw", lo cual se traduce en que la string se evualuará tal cual, sin hacer ningún escape de caracteres (esto es una *buena práctica* al trabajar con expresiones regulares. Te ahorrará más de un dolor de cabeza).
2. A la string `"[{}]"` se le está aplicando una [interpolación](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation) para que así lo que está dentro del método `format()` se sustituya dentro de las llaves (`{}`).
3. El método `join()` de la clase `str` (lo que está dentro de `format()`), iterará sobre la lista `puntuation` y generará una string que contenga unidos todos los elementos de la lista recién mencionada. Para nuestro caso esta sería: `',; '`
4. Como dije, el contenido de `pattern` debe ser una regex, y luego de todo esto quedará de la siguiente manera: `r'[,; ]'`. Esto es una expresión regular conocida como [Character Classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#:%7E:text=With%20a%20%E2%80%9Ccharacter%20class%E2%80%9D%2C,match%20either%20gray%20or%20grey.). Esto hará que el engine haga match con cualquiera de los caracteres que estén dentro de los corchetes.

Comment: Me encanto tu detallada explicación Revliscano. ¡Excelente!

Comment: Cuidado con caracteres especiales, que lo harían fallar (`^`, `-`, `]`, ```\```) ... Si quisieras sacar los elementos vacíos intermedios, sería más sencillo cambiar el regex a `[,; ]+`

Answer (score 2):

te dejo un código usando `regular expresions` que creo que te podría funcionar. Lo que hace es literal dividir la cadena si ve un espacio `" "`, un punto y coma`";"` o una coma `","`

```
import re
var = re.split(r'[\s,;]+','hola, como; estas?')

print(var)
```

La página que te recomiendo literal es la documentación oficial de la librería `re`:

[Documentación RE](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/re.html)

Espero te haya servido, aquí la salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡Saludos!

Comment: Buena explicación también, Ricardo.